# Can we build a Naive Bayes model in the presence of multicollinearity?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

There exists multi-collinearity in the model. As a result(may be) the accuracy of Naive Bayes model is less than logistic regression model(model is built with the help of PCA). So, is there any method to build Naive Bayes model in the presence of multi-collinearity?

Answer (score 3):

One of the assumptions of Naive Bayes is [class-conditional independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#:%7E:text=Now%20the%20%22naive%22%20conditional%20independence%20assumptions%20come%20into%20play%3A%20assume%20that%20all%20features%20in). If your data lacks this property (by way of multi-collinearity), then perhaps Naive Bayes will not be the right choice. It's worth noting, though, that your data does not need to exhibit independence, in general. Instead it is independence conditioned on the class. These are two different things.

Regardless though, you will be able to fit a Naive Bayes model. Plus, the broken assumptions may not be the end of the world. [This paper (published at AAAI 2004)](https://aaai.org/papers/flairs-2004-097/) goes into more detail as to why Naive Bayes sometimes performs well in spite of broken assumptions.

Comment: Naive Bayes could still be a good model, the posterior probabilities will likely be inaccurate .